# How to expand an image in customtkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm displaying an image in a label, and when i'm expanding the window, the image remains the same size.
What can I do to expand the image?

```
def display_image(self, image_path):
        # Load image
        self.my_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(image_path), size=(700, 300))
        self.image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.graph_frame, image=self.my_image, text="")  
        self.image_label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

Comment: How did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: You can update the `size` option of `CTkImage` whenever the window is resized.